# Fetch XML feed from external file with AngularJS

Tags: xml, angularjs

I am trying to fetch an XML feed from the same domain but the obj is returning null. Below is my code.

**Service**

```
angular.module('ngAuidApp')
  .service('profileInfoService', function($http){
    return $http.get('scripts/user-feed.xml');
  });
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('ngAuidApp')
  .controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', 'x2js', 'profileInfoService', function ($scope, x2js, profileInfoService) {

    var xmlObj = '<feed><title type="text">User Ashish Panchal - Stack Overflow</title><link rel="self" href="http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/3635285" type="application/atom+xml" /><link rel="alternate" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/3635285" type="text/html" /></feed>';

    var jsonOb = x2js.xml_str2json(xmlObj);

    // Prints title from above xml string
    console.log(jsonOb.feed.title);

    // Trying to fetch from external file
    profileInfoService.success(function(data){
      // Print outs xml feed
      console.log(data);

      var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json(data);

      // Prints null
      console.log(jsonObj);

    });
  }]);
```

When I am trying to fetch feed from external file it gives null. Can someone please let me know what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

error in your xml file not in code.
Please remove this ":" from you xml attribute Example change

```
<re:rank> to <rerank>
```

Comment: You're right, my script was correct. There was problem with my xml feed, I took new feed and it worked.... btw I don't need to rename the <re:rank>.